# JS: Проблема с конфигуратором

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS, пытаюсь ршить задачку от HTML Acedemy, получаю странные ошибки.

Задача выглядит так:

```
let materialPrice = {
  'wood': 1000,
  'stone': 1500,
  'brick': 2000
};

let house = {
  rooms: 10,
  floors: 5,
  material: 'wood',
  coefficient: 10.5
};

/* Техническое задание

Мяу! Допиши за меня конфигуратор. Я создал объект house и задал ему несколько свойств: rooms (количество комнат), floors (этажи), material (материал для стен), coefficient (средняя площадь каждой комнаты).

Ещё я завёл мапу materialPrice, в которой записал стоимость каждого возможного материала для строительства.

Добавь в объект два метода: calculateSquare, который будет возвращать площадь дома, и calculatePrice, который будет возвращать стоимость строительства.

Площадь считай так: умножь количество комнат на коэффициент и число этажей в доме.

Цена строительства — произведение площади и стоимости материала дома.

*/
```

Вот мое решение:

```
let materialPrice = {
  'wood': 1000,
  'stone': 1500,
  'brick': 2000
};

let buildHouse = function (rooms, floors, material, coefficient) {
  
let house = {
  rooms: 10,
  floors: 5,
  material: 'wood',
  coefficient: 10.5,

  calculateSquare: function () {
    return this.rooms * this.coefficient * this.floors;
    },
    
  calculatePrice: function () {
    return calculateSquare * materialPrice[this[material]];
    }
}  


return house;
}

buildHouse();
```

Получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал разные варианты, в том числе мапил атрибутиы переданные через функцию:

```
 let house = {
      rooms: rooms,
      floors: floors,
      material: material,
      coefficient: coefficient
    };
```

Пробовал создавать и вызывать функцию ниже объекта home. Пробовал много всего и получаю либо что объект house удален, либо что метод calculateSquare не определен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не `Square`, а `Area`.

```
//let buildHouse = function (rooms, floors, material, coefficient) {
  
let house = {
  rooms: 10,
  floors: 5,
  material: 'wood',
  coefficient: 10.5,

  calculateSquare: function () {
    return this.rooms * this.coefficient * this.floors;
  },
    
  calculatePrice: function () {
    return this.calculateSquare() * materialPrice[this.material];
  }
}  

//return house;
//}
```

Comment: Увы, тогда появляется ошиба "Переменная material не определена"

Comment: Да я бы назвал calculateArea, но по условию они просят называть ее calculateSquare

Comment: @Rumata `materialPrice[this.material];`

Comment: Да! Спасибо большое!